# ASP.NET Core 6 - How to return port of Angular Live Development Server via CreatedAtAction

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, http-headers, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to use `CreatedAtAction` to return the URL to a newly created ressource in my ASP.NET Core 6 based web application. Here is an example:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProgram([FromBody] Program body)
{
    int programId = {Create program...};

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetProgram), new { id = programId }, null);
}
```

For the frontend I am using Angular 12 and the Angular Live Development Server while developing the application. The development server is running on port 4200. The web application itself (backend) is running on another port, for example 5001.

When I now create a new program through the frontend, it does a POST request to port `http://localhost:4200/...`. However, in the response coming from the backend, the location-header points to `https://localhost:5001/...`:
[image: location-header-problem]

The actual URL is correct, but the protocol (http/https) and the port are not. How can I make the backend use the same protocol and port in the location-header that was used for the request, or is this not necessary? I did not setup this solution to begin with, so I am not even entirely sure why it even routes all requests through the angular server.

Comment: Please allow me to post some of my ideas here, I'm not sure if I understand your requirement clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend will receive the request from your Angular app, and the input request has a url like `https://localhost:4200/...`. And the same, your Angular app will receive response coming from your asp.net core backend, which input url is like `https://localhost:5001/...`. It should be the expected behaviour as one server can expose one port at the same time, so your 2 application are supposed to have different ports.

If you wanna make them have the same port, you can deploy them in 2 different servers, so they will have different origins but can have the same port.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I think there is a small missunderstanding. I do not want to run both applications on the same port. However, I noticed that by returning from an action via `CreatedAtAction` as in my example, the location-header of the http response (which the frontend receives) contains an URL which has the port of the backend server. I do not think that this is the correct behavior, or is it? This isn't about a specific requirement which I have but rather about a strange behaviour which I think isn't correct.

Comment: I added a screenshot to my question which hopefully makes my problem more clear.

Comment: If there's no error, then I think it's the common behavior

Comment: There can't be an error yet because so far I am not using the location-header in the frontend. This will only be the case when I start using it to request the data for the newly created ressource (which will happen at some point). I just find it weird that everything would go through the angular server, but in this case it will have a URL straight to the backend server. But as I already said, I have no idea if this is "normal" or problematic under any circumstances. I just think it's a bit weird.

Comment: hmmm, I found a thing, that is `http://localhost:4200`, and the response is `https://localhost:5001`,  http and https exposed different ports.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I didn't even notice that. I am running it via http during development but the production version will run on Azure via https. Anyway, I still have no idea how exactly this is "supposed" to work and if this behaviour is normal or not. Maybe there is a mistake in the configuration of this project somewhere but I really am clueless about this. It just doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: I can't give a convincing evidence to prove it's necessary.....